# For loops to plot two outputs in sequence in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm trying to write a double `for` loop to plot two outputs in sequence.

Based on the two following vectors:

```
vec.a <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
vec.b <- c("b1", "b2", "b3")
```

I tried the first loop:

```
for (i in vec.a){
    cat(i)
    for (j in vec.b){
        cat(j, "| ")
    }
}
```

And the output was:

`a1b1 | b2 | b3 | a2b1 | b2 | b3 | a3b1 | b2 | b3 |`

I tried a second loop:

```
for (i in vec.a){
    for (j in vec.b){
        cat(i)
        cat(j, "| ")
    }
}
```

And the output was:

`a1b1 | a1b2 | a1b3 | a2b1 | a2b2 | a2b3 | a3b1 | a3b2 | a3b3 |`

**But the output desired is:**

`a1b1 | a2b2 | a3b3`

How to do this?

**Update:**

I want to compare the graphics between the columns in the same position of the two data frames. But the sequence shown is not that I desire. I think that the logic is the same of the example above.

```
set.seed(99)
df.a <- matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 10,  # 10 rows and 10 columns
           dimnames=list(paste("p", 1:10, sep = ""), 
                         paste("sp.A", 1:10, sep = ""))) 

df.b <- matrix(rnorm(50), 20, 10,  # 20 rows and 10 columns
           dimnames=list(paste("p", 1:20, sep = ""), 
                         paste("sp.B", 1:10, sep = "")))
```

To compare the graphics, I used something like this:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
invisible(lapply(colnames(df.a[ ,1:ncol(df.a)]), function(x){
   invisible(lapply(colnames(df.b[ ,1:ncol(df.b)]), function(w){
     plot(df.a[ ,x], main = x) 
     plot(df.b[ ,w], main = w)
   }))
}))
```

How to plot the first column of the `df.a` paired with the first column of the `df.b`, and so on?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You will need equal number of rows in the two matrices though, otherwise plot() will try to do draw two vectors of unequal length (try plot(1:10, 1:20))!

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean, ignore the comment above. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you are looking for `mapply`

```
mapply(FUN = cat, vec.a, vec.b, MoreArgs = list("| ", sep = ""))
```

wrapping the above in `invisible()` suppresses the output from `mapply`

```
invisible(mapply(FUN = cat, vec.a, vec.b, MoreArgs = list("| ", sep = "")))
```

**Solution using for loop:**
The following code produces the same output, but using a for loop

```
for (i in seq_along(vec.a)){
   cat(vec.a[i], vec.b[i], "|", sep = "")
}
```

**Solution for updated question**

```
set.seed(99)
df.a <- matrix(rnorm(50), 10, 10,  # 10 rows and 10 columns
               dimnames=list(paste("p", 1:10, sep = ""), 
                             paste("sp.A", 1:10, sep = ""))) 

df.b <- matrix(rnorm(50), 20, 10,  # 20 rows and 10 columns
               dimnames=list(paste("p", 1:20, sep = ""), 
                             paste("sp.B", 1:10, sep = ""))) 
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
for (i in 1:ncol(df.a)){
  plot(df.a[ ,i], main = i) 
  plot(df.b[ ,i], main = i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we paste the two vector together, which will bind them cell by cell. Them we bind all cells together to create one single string, using " | " as collapse parameter.

```
# Creating the vectors
vec.a <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
vec.b <- c("b1", "b2", "b3")

# Creating the output
paste(vec.a,vec.b,sep="",collapse=" | ")
```

Output:

```
"a1b1 | a2b2 | a3b3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I really need to use some iteration, like a `for`. I tried to simplify the question using the `cat`. However, I will use the solution to run and to plot two correlograms based on two data frames with different dimensions each one.

Comment: Can you shows us an example of what you want as output?

Comment: @KarloGuidoniMartins In your example, you have shown vec.a and vec.b as vectors, but you mention data frames in your comment? Also, when you say the data frames have different dimensions, do they have the same number of rows? Other than that, the for loop is straightforward, you just want to loop through the corresponding elements in each vector (see my updated answer below).

Comment: I'll edit the question and add another example below.